# Study the quality of sets (open, close, compact)

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Study the nature of sets $A,B$ (i.e. open, close, compact).

Let $$A= \{(x_1, x_2, .. ,x_6) \in \mathbb{R}^6 \ | \ \ (x_1,x_2), (x_3,x_4), (x_5,x_6) \text{ form a triangle } \}$$

$$B=\{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R^6} \ | \ \ a \le b \le c\le d \le 1 ,\ \ a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 < 4\}$$

My try:

> Focusing on $A$, can we describe a circle in our triangles such that our set looks like $$\displaystyle A= \{(x_1, x_2, .. ,x_6) \in \mathbb{R}^6 \ |\ \ x^2_1+x^2_2=r^2,\ \ x^2_3+x^2_4=r^2,\ \ x^2_5+x^2_6=r^2 \}?$$

For $B$ I want to divide it into smaller sets and take an intersecion of them, but then I get 4 closed set's and 1 open set.

Can I conclude that set B is neither open or closed ?
Or it's not sufficient ?

Comment: What exactly does "triangle" mean in $A$? A planar triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Does the triangle have to be nondegenerate?

Comment: it means a set of points that aren't collinear